# HTML text box with two button

Tags: html, css

below my code i need it in the same width and height but with multiple lines "start from the first line" and when reached end of the line go to the new line  and 120 characters only and as i made it with "Enter text message" hide when you click to right but i need it with gray color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a textarea with maxlength and placeholder attribtues (html5).
Add resize:none to your css.
Do not forget to replace maxlength 10 by 120, I used 10 to test quicker :)

You will reach your goal.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DMZG7/5/)

```
<textarea maxlength="10" style="width:300px; height:70px" name="tb" type="text" placeholder="Enter text message" ></textarea>
```

Comment: the second one AMAZING but i need it fixed size no one can change the size and 120 char ONLY

Answer (score 2):

instead of values u can use this option

```
Placeholder="enter text message"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the placeholder attribute in a textarea tag. Thats what you are looking for

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"><br>
  <textarea  type="text" placeholder="Enter text message" ></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use text area

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" Placeholder="enter text message">

</textarea>
```

Text Area allows you to enter multiple line